# How to navigate through the mat-vertical-stepper in same component

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat, mat-stepper

i am building a website,
In registration form i am using mat-vertical stepper it has 5 mat-steps
1)personal Info
2)Investment profile
3)account Info
4)setup Funding
5)sign in and submit

In sign in and submit all the information from the previous mat-step labels are retrieved with their corresponding mat-step-Labels.

My problem here is each mat-Step-Label has an edit icon when user clicks on it it should go to particular mat-step and edit the content .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is mat-stepper's default behavior, just follow the official document
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#stepper-variants

and here is a stack blitz site for your reference
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-stepper?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html